# VBA Spell check specific cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm using a macro to, among other things, spell check an invoice I've created in Excel before I save it.  Currently, it spell checks the entire workbook.  I'd like to spell check only certian cells of a specific sheet  (because I don't want to spell check peoples names and addresses on the invoice).

Specifically, I'd like to spell check only cells D15-D19 on sheet "Invoice"  and cell D38 on sheet "Safety Inspection"

Can someone point me in the right direction?

This is the VBA code that I'm currently using that I'd like to refine:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveAsSafety()
 'Saves filename as value of A1 plus the current date


Application.CommandBars("Tools").Controls("Spelling...").Execute
 'Invokes spell check

Dim newFile As String, fName As String
 ' Don't use "/" in date, invalid syntax
fName = Range("M9").Value
 'Change the date format to whatever you'd like, but make sure it's in quotes
newFile = fName & " - " & Range("D10").Value & " - " & Range("D9")
 ' Change directory to suit your PC, including USER NAME

Sheets(Array("Safety Inspection", "Invoice")).Select
Sheets("Safety Inspection").Activate

ChDir _
"C:\Users\Brian\Google Drive\Buller Heating and Air\Invoices"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFile
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Range("A1").Value _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: you're almost there. you already have the proper sheets array, you can add a range addresses array and then iterate over the two of them simultaneously to gather both a sheet and the corresponding range over which act with your spell routine (which you didn't include in the above code)

Answer (score 1):

To check spelling in specific cells try:

```
Sub bbuller()
    Dim boo As Boolean

    s = Array("Invoice!D15", "Invoice!D16", "Invoice!D17", "Invoice!D18", "Invoice!D19", "'Safety Inspection'!D38")
    For Each ss In s
        boo = CheckItNew(Range(ss))
        If boo Then
            MsgBox ss & " has no errors"
        Else
            MsgBox ss & " has errors"
        End If
    Next ss
End Sub

Public Function CheckItNew(r As Range) As Boolean
    Dim MyText As String
    MyText = r(1).Text
    Dim oxlAp As Object
    Set oxlAp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    CheckItNew = oxlAp.CheckSpelling(MyText)
    oxlAp.Quit
    Set oxlAp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I learned something new (once again!). I'd add that since the OP's environment is Excel it could be avoided `CheckItNew` function and directly go with `If Application.CheckSpelling(Range(ss)(1).Text) Then`